# What is the difference between functions in Python and functions in C++?

Tags: python, c++, function

What i basically mean to ask is, in python, a function is defined and when the program is run, it does not return anything as long as we don't call it. I recently started learning C++, and here i saw that a function is defined using int main() and doesnt have to be called in order to execute the block of code within the function. How does this work? How is a function in python different than that in C++?

Comment: In C/C++, the `main()` function is the program entry point.  In Python, the program entry point is just the top of whatever module you execute with `python myscript.py`.

Comment: @JohnGordon so for any function in c++, the program automatically enters the function right? no need to call it separately like in the case of python?

Comment: No, all functions must be called by your code, with the exception of main() - that's automatically the starting point of every C/C++ program, regardless of where it is. Think of main() as "insert code you want to get executed in here".

Comment: ahhhh thamks @Alex

Comment: No problem! Also it should be pointed out that your program will EXIT when the main function is finished, too - you want to put literally all your code in there, with the exception of includes, class/struct/enum/macro/function/etc. definitions and global variables.

Comment: @Alex oh cool. i literally started c++ yesterday and moving over from python its night and day so i dont really know understand most of the c++ terms people fling around anyway :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C/C++, the `main()` function is the program entry point.

In python their is no such `main()` functions which are the program entry point and don't automatically run unless they are called. But the behaviour cam be implemented.

```
def main():
  # Your code

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Then `main()` will run if script is **executed** (**not imported**)

Also python does not require `main()` functions like C++, all code in the script outside any function (which is not called)  is executed

Comment: in c++, the program automatically enters functions during execution right? no need to call them separately like in the case of python?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but you need to call all function except main() in c++

Comment: Python does not require any `main()` function unlike C++. You can consider the entire code itself to be wrapped in an _imaginary_ `main` function in Python.